# How to echo the row into my html?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to do the next thing:

Select the row title from table movies, and display the answer between the `<h3></h3>` tags.

This is what i have now.

```
$sql = "SELECT title FROM movies";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  


?>


<div class="grids">
<div class="grid">
                    <h3>
<?php {
    echo "" . $row["title"]. "";
}
}?>
</h3>
```

The 2 div classes are being ended somewhere further in the code. When i add plain text between the h3 tags, it works perfectly.

Also this works perfectly, but it is not echoed on the place where i want it to be:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT title FROM movies";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "" . $row["title"]. " <br>";
}
} ?>
```

how can i make it echo right between the tags?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want the row title inside `div.grids`? Inside `div.grid`? Please let us know the desired HTML structure.

Comment: Don't forget to use `htmlspecialchars()` around any arbitrary data used in the context of HTML.  Otherwise, you risk generated invalid HTML and even injecting malicious scripts depending on where your data comes from.

Answer (score 4):

Do the output inside the element -

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT title FROM movies";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
?>

<div class="grids">
<?php 
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           echo '<div class="grid">';
           echo '<h3>' .  $row["title"] . '</h3>';
           // you can echo other info inside the grid
           echo '</div>';
       }
    } 
?>
</div><!-- ends grids -->
```

Comment: You the *leader of the pack* now ;)

Comment: I was feeling a little packed ;)

Comment: After all that fun you had, I'd believe it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should echo the  tags with php.
It's very easy and provides clean code.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "<h3>" . $row["title"]. "</h3><br>"; //This is the key part... the <h3> tags are printed inside the loop
}
}
```

You just need to place this code wherever you want to display the rows data.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...the problem is that you begin your loop after that h3 tag...the fail-output, which you get, puts all the title inside the h3 tag

You should do something like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo "<h3>".$row['title']."</h3>";
}
```

Comment: I hope you don't really mean `while ()`. As in a while loop with nothing inside the parentheses. If so then this answer is really wrong.

Comment: No i do not really mean only while (), it should only show the right construct

Comment: I recommend editing your answer then, otherwise people will get the wrong idea.

Comment: hope u re happy now :-)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to control how it outputs is simply putting the html code in the echo tags like so:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<div class="grids"><div class="grid"><h3>" . $row["title"]. " <h3>";
}
```

Or if you want the output to be a little cleaner like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT title FROM movies";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { //Your curly brace({) was not here so it probably wasn't outputting correctly
?>
<div class="grids">
    <div class="grid">
       <h3><?php echo $row["title"; ?></h3>
<?php } ?>
```

Note that you can also use the `while: ... endwhile;` structure for while loops to help with legibility.
And I would probably avoid not closing the div tags here where the loop is, unless of course you are doing another query somewhere else.  You could probably do a query like `SELECT title, description, link FROM movies` then output the results with code along the lines of:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
    <div class="grids">
        <div class="grid">
           <h3><?php echo $row["title"; ?></h3>
           <div><?php echo $row["description"]; ?></div>
           <div><?php echo $row["link"]; ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

That does a few things: 
1. It helps to eliminate double queries which slows down the page when it renders.
2. It also helps ensure that you are closing the divs with the right amount of closing divs.
3. It is a lot easier to read compared to having multiple queries asking for the same table just different data sets.  If you need multiple tables you should read up on SQL JOIN clauses.

One other thing to note.  The query should have the columns that exist in your database, I was just guessing some names so that may not work..